# Umbraco Contour displaying ampersand (&) as &amp; in questions

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco-contour

I've recently installed Contour for a client and in one of the questions in the form there's an ampersand (&) but its rendering as `&amp;`

I've tried rendering the form both in RTE and via the template itself but still the same result.

The client is running Umbraco v4.7.2 and Contour v3.0.6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Let me try a few suggestions in hopes that you can let us know what you are experiencing...

> On the template are you using an inline macro (i.e. - calling the content using `@Model.bodyContent`) or,
>
> Are you calling the umbraco field with `<umbraco:Item field="bodyContent" runat="server" />`
>
> If you are calling the value from within a macro, try wrapping the output in `@Html.Raw(bodyContent)`
>
> Secondly, try using the form picker datatype that comes with Contour.  Add it to your doctype and render the form using the RenderMacroContent method.  If you need the full script to get this working let me know in reply, but this link (https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/rendermacrocontent) should help.

Finally, check the contour files and edit the *ContourForm.cshtml* file.  Try using `@Html.Raw()` around the `@f.Caption` output within the `<label>` tag.

It is hard to be too specific without some additional clues and troubleshooting, but this is where I would start.  Any additional information you can provide will allow me to edit my answer and provide more assistance.